# Where does Xcode's open quickly search?

Tags: xcode

I'm not sure how to get it to index my project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I installed 10.6, I have been able to use the open quickly dialog to open anything in my user search path.

I am not sure if this is because of Snow Leopard, Xcode 3.2, the re-install, etc…

Check after you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Open Quickly should be searching any *open* projects. There used to be a Preference for paths but I believe it was removed with 3.1?!?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that said header file is not on your project's include path?  If you added your source folders to your project using the "Create Folder References" option, or if you are using an external build system, then Xcode's indexer will not be aware of that file.

If you had added folders with the "Create Folder References" option, then there would be some folder icons in your project's file list that are yellow instead of the usual blue.  If this is the case, you might try removing those folder references and re-adding the folders with the  "Recursively create groups" option.

If you are using an external build system (which I suspect is not the case, since this is an iPhone question), then you have to explicitly tell Xcode about your project's include path by setting the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` option in the Build panel of your project's Info window.

Another possibility is that the file you are trying to Open Quickly might be in a Framework that you have not added to your project.  If that is the case, adding the framework will fix it.

Comment: “If you had added … Folder References…, then there would be some folder icons … that are yellow instead of the usual blue.” Other way around. Groups are beige; folder references are blue (like the folders themselves are in the Finder).