# How do I control the "open quickly" search path in XCode3 (3.2.3)?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

XCode2 had this beautiful feature: you put the cursor on a line with a `#include <file>` and execute the open-quickly command (command-shift-D) and it would open the file.  I can't get it to work for me in XCode3.

I have something like this

```
#include <folder/subfolder/HeaderFile.hh>
```

and when I put the cursor on this line, and open the open-quickly dialog, it automatically fills the search window with

```
folder/subfolder/HeaderFile.hh
```

but doesn't find anything.  If I then remove "folder/subfolder/" then the dialog will identify HeaderFile.hh and I can open it up.  But this extra deleting is so much slower just the three-key command-shift-D opening I was used to with XCode2.

If I give it the full path to this file in the search window, then it finds it:

```
/Users/andrew/myproject/src/folder/subfolder/HeaderFile.hh
```

this path will find the file.  Again, I don't want to spend all my time typing out the full path.

I created this project as an external build system, and I think that's related to the problem; the xcode project lives in

```
/Users/andrew/myproject/xcp_dir/
```

and I want it to search in the "../src/" directory so that the partial path I give it (which is already present in the #include) will match the file I want to open.  In XCode3, I had to create the project in the xcp_dir directory; in XCode2, I could create the project directly into the existing myproject/ directory -- maybe that's why the search is failing?

I read on a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972580/where-does-xcodes-open-quickly-search) (which never answered the question) that I should set the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` option.  I tried this (setting the option to `/Users/andrew/myproject/src`) but it did not work.

I don't have any sense of what other options (like the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS option) are availalbe, so if you know which one I have to set, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: It may be worth installing Xcode 3.2.5 and trying it in there. You can install Xcode 3.2.5 in an entirely separate folder as Xcode 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an old question I'll answer it for Xcode 4 instead of 3.

As far as I know Open Quickly doesn't use anything like a search path. It seems to have use the project's codesense index and will show results from that. Querying the database doesn't have an notion of file paths, so the workflow you describe just won't work anymore.

However that's okay, because there's a better solution: Just <kbd>⌘</kbd>+click on the include line and the appropriate file will be found using the same rules as the compiler uses, and opened. If you want to open the file up in an assistant, another tab or window, you can use <kbd>⇧⌘</kbd>+click instead, and you'll get a little UI for easily selecting where you want the file opened.

You can also use these shortcuts to go to definitions for any identifier.

If you don't want to use the mouse you can use the command "Jump to Definition" which has the shortcut <kbd>⌃⌘J</kbd>, or <kbd>⌥⌃⌘J</kbd> to open the definition in the assistant editor. This also works for both normal identifiers and `#included` files.